# Using eclipse editor shortcuts in scala worksheet in Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala

How do I enable the typical editing keyboard shortcuts for .scala files in Scala worksheets as well?

For e.g., I use Cmd-/ to comment code in my .scala files. However, this shortcut does not work in a Scala worksheet

Answer (score 1):

If you got to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations  you will see that scala worksheets (.sc files) are mapped to a different editor than the scala files.

What you really need is for the editor to handle all the same shortcuts. (it does handle copy/paste and many other shortcuts)   It's possible you could add another editor in the chain above the scala scripting engine.

Updated:  Change the mapping for the .sc extension so that from top to bottom it reads 1. Java Editor  2. Text Editor  3. Scala Script Editor.  I can confirm that works.

Comment: I made the update but it still does not work :(. I have the same order(Java Editor is the default,then Text editor,then Scala Script Editor). I restarted Eclipse too. I have a shiny new Scala IDE. Is it possible that you had made some related change sometime in the past, which I have to make too? Thanks for trying!

Comment: and when I open a new worksheet, it opens it in Java Editor mode, where I lose out on the interactive update of results when I save the worksheet